# C# - I am trying to create a grid lock game and I need your assistance

Tags: c#, grid-layout

Since I don't have 10 reputation to post an image, I am going to leave a link of the game picture. http://thinkfun.com/mathcounts/play-rush-hour

This is what I want to create. A game where a rectangle must pass through other rectangles through the hole to win the game. The main rectangle can only move forward and other rectangles can move either right, left, up or down depending on their position. You must move the other rectangles in a way that they could make a way for the main rectangle to pass.

Here is my plan how I am going to create this game:

1. Create all the forms, import all the images and graphics to get ready to work with them.
2. Write code for 1 rectangle that would be able to move around.
3. Write an algorithm that wouldn't allow for rectangles to go through each other.
4. Make a winning hole.
5. Code other rectangles, make a full game.
6. Make fancy animations.
7. Import statistics : score, move counter and etc.

Here are my questions that I wanted to ask before trying to develop this game.

(Oh, and by the way, I am using Visual Studio C# form )

1. I assume that these rectangles are not going to be buttons, then what kind of a "button" (or whatever you call those extra features ) should I use?
2. How do I make a skin for those rectangles? So I can make it look like wood and make a nice skin for the main rectangle.

These are all my questions so far. I would like to know how to overcome those problems and I would like to hear some extra tips. Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Use a **PictureBox** for your Rectangles...

Comment: Hi Valdas, I think the word you're looking for to describe buttons, as well as 'extra features', is 'control'. Regarding what control should you use, that's up to you and making a skin for it is dependent on what control you choose. I think you would achieve better results personally and for your game by following some basic game design tutorials rather than asking this question on stackoverflow. Best of luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [Graphics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da0f23z7(v=vs.110).aspx) to draw your rectangles. Else make an object to hold info for it and you can import an `Image` as your "skin".
2. See number 1.

Comment: private void Form1_Paint(object sender,
       System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs pe)
        {
            Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(@"C:\rectangle-wood-sign-minnesota.jpg");
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(myBitmap);
       } I don't know how to use Stackoverflow text editor....

Comment: Since I don't know how to use this stackoverflow comment section, I can't format the code and go to a new line... SO I added this function to my code and what do I do now? Is this correct?

Comment: I'm not going to write your code for you mate. Just add the files as resources and then load them in at "game time" hence the benefit of creating an object.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what to do... Never worked with graphics before... Also I am not really asking for the code, I just want to import the structures and stuff, then write code for myself.

Answer (score 0):

First off: Do you want to create a game or learn winForms? If the answer is create a game. Chose a Game Engine (Unity is nice, and uses c#) and work with that instead.

If you want to learn winForms you'd probably want a PictureBox, then add your code your code in OnMouseUp, OnMouseDown, etc. Good luck :)

Comment: I think learning winForms would be the best skill to accomplish in the world. Unity is a really strange platform that I am struggling using, like I am really really struggling with unity. Also, thanks for the comment, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Not a problem! But to emphasize, Unity is good if you want to create games. Windows forms is good if you want to create software. If you try to create games in windows forms you'll run into all kinds of problems (yes-I've tried) first off there is no true transparency. Second off the screen might update when you don't want it to, causing things to flicker. Further more things will be slow.  My point is, if you make this game as an intro to games use Unity or Some other GameEngine/Framework, if you make this games because it's a good intro to other software use windows forms.